How to fix the issue with some post functions not working during autopagination?
I need help solving a problem with automatic pagination. When automatic  pagination occurs from the home_list.html template to the home.html template, all functions of the template stop working, even though the template itself is paginated correctly. The functionality stops working after pagination, namely: "edit" and "delete" the published post, "Add comment", "Edit comment", "Save edited comment", "Delete comment".
In the home.html template, these functions work in the {% for post in post_lists %} loop, but after automatic pagination from the home_list.html template in the {% for post in posts %} loop, these functions do not work. How can I fix this?
home.html
<div id="post_contenter">
{% for post in post_lists %}

<div class="post_content" id="post_content"> <!-- Add identifier post_content -->
    <div class="post_header">
        <div class="post_user_avatar">
            {% if post.author.avatar %}
                <img style="width:50px; height: 50px;" src="{{ post.author.avatar.url }}" class="user-picture-small">
            {% else %}
                <img style="width:50px; height: 50px;" src="{% static 'twippie/img/avatar.png' %}" class="card_user_picture_small">
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="post_user_info">
            <div class="post_user_fullname"><a href="{% url 'user:profile_username' post.author.username %}" class="post_user_fullname_style">{{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }}</a></div>
            <div class="post_user_username"><a href="{{ user_profile.username }}" class="post_user_nickname_style">@{{ post.author }}</a>

                 {% if post.author.verification %}
    <span class="verified_user_small"></span>
                {% endif %}

            </div>
            <div class="post_user_date"><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" class="post_user_date_style">{{ post.time_create }} {{ post.time_create|naturaltime }}</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_user_more">
        <div class="dropdown dropbtn" style="float:right;">
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                {% if request.user == post.author %}
                    <span><a href="{% url 'edit_post' post_slug=post.slug %}" class="post_user_edit">Edit</a></span>
                {% endif %}
                {% if user.is_authenticated and user == post.author %}
                    <span><a href="{% url 'delete_post' post_slug=post.slug %}" class="post_user_delete">Delete post</a></span>
                {% endif %}

                <span><a href="" class="post_user_complain">Report</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_user_content">
        {{ post.content }}
    </div>
    <div class="post_user_action">



<div class="post_user_liked_post">


{% if liked_by_current_user %}
    <div class="unlike-button" id="unlike-button-{{ post.id }}" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}"></div>
{% else %}
    <div class="like-button" id="like-button-{{ post.id }}" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}"></div>
{% endif %}
    <div class="count_likevalue">
        <span class="like-count-value like_count_style" id="like-count-{{ post.id }}" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">{{ like_count }}</span>
    </div>


</div>

        <div class="containercomment_post">
            <!-- Unique identifier for each post -->
    <div class="post_user_comment_post" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">
        <span class="count_comment">{{ post.comments.count }}</span>
    </div>

        </div>
        <div class="post_user_share_post"></div>
        <div class="post_user_views_post">
            <div class="post_user_views_post_count"><span class="post_user_views_post_count_style">125025</span></div>
        </div>

    </div>



            <!-- Unique identifier for each comment form -->
    <div class="comment-form hidden" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">
        <hr>
        <form action="{% url 'add_comment' post_id=post.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <textarea name="content" class="user_comment_style" placeholder="Write a comment..." required></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="img_sbmt"></button>
        </form>
    </div>

<!-- Display all comments -->
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <div class="comment-container">
        <div class="comment_post">
            {% if comment.author.avatar %}
                <img src="{{ comment.author.avatar.url }}" class="comment_author_img_style">
            {% else %}
                <img src="{% static 'twippie/img/avatar.png' %}" class="comment_author_img_style">
            {% endif %}
            <div class="comment_author"><a href="{% url 'user:profile_username' username=comment.author.username %}">{{ comment.author.first_name }}</a></div>
            <div class="comment_content" id="comment-content-{{ comment.id }}">{{ comment.content }}</div>
            <div class="comment_time">{{ comment.created_at }}
                <!--<span class="answer_comment_user"><a>Reply</a></span>-->
{% if comment.author == request.user %}
    <span id="edit-actions-{{ comment.id }}" class="edit_comment_user">
        <a href="#" onclick="editComment({{ comment.id }})" class="edit_comment_link">edit</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="saveComment(event, {{ comment.id }})" class="save_comment_link" style="display: none;">Save changes</a>
    </span>
    <span class="delete_comment_user"><a href="{% url 'delete_comment' comment_id=comment.id %}">delete</a></span>
{% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if not forloop.last %}
            <!-- If the current comment is not the last one, add a separator -->
            <hr class="solid_bottom">
        {% endif %}
        <span class="massage_save_comment_error"></span> <!-- Error message -->
        <span id="save-message-{{ comment.id }}" class="massage_save_comment"></span> <!-- Save message -->
    </div>
{% endfor %}
    <br>
</div>

{% endfor %}

<div id="pagination-loader" class="pagination_pages" data-page="1"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loadedPage = 1; // Variable to store the loaded page number

    // Function to load the next batch of posts
    function loadNextPage() {
        // Perform an AJAX request to the server
        var nextPageUrl = '/load-posts/?page=' + (loadedPage + 1);
        console.log("Next page URL:", nextPageUrl);

        $.ajax({
            url: nextPageUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("Response from server:", response);

                // Check if there is data about posts in the JSON response
                if (response.posts) {
                    // Add HTML with posts to the end of the container
                    $('#post_contenter').append(response.html_posts);

                    // Check if there are more posts on the next page
                    if (response.next_page_url) {
                        // Increase the value of the loadedPage variable
                        loadedPage++;
                    } else {
                        // If there is no next page, hide the loading indicator
                        $('#pagination-loader').hide();
                    }
                } else {
                    // If there is no data about posts, display an error message
                    console.error('Error loading posts: data about posts is missing in the JSON response');
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Handle the error if it occurred during the request
                console.error('Error loading posts:', textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

    // Event handler for scrolling the page
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        // Get the current scroll position
        var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        // Get the height of the browser window
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        // Get the height of the entire document
        var documentHeight = $(document).height();
        
        // If the user has scrolled to the end of the page
        if (scrollPosition + windowHeight >= documentHeight) {
            // Check if the loading indicator is visible
            if ($('#pagination-loader').is(':visible')) {
                // Load the next batch of posts
                loadNextPage();
            }
        }
    });

    // Check if the first page of posts needs to be loaded when the page is loaded
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        loadNextPage();
    }
});
</script>
<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

home_list.html:
{% load humanize %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% if posts %}
    <div class="post-list">
        {% for post in posts %}
            {% if not forloop.first and post.author != request.user %}
           <div class="post_content" id="post_content"> <!-- Add identifier post_content -->
    <div class="post_header">
        <div class="post_user_avatar">
            {% if post.author.avatar %}
                <img style="width:50px; height: 50px;" src="{{ post.author.avatar.url }}" class="user-picture-small">
            {% else %}
                <img style="width:50px; height: 50px;" src="{% static 'twippie/img/avatar.png' %}" class="card_user_picture_small">
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="post_user_info">
            <div class="post_user_fullname"><a href="{% url 'user:profile_username' post.author.username %}" class="post_user_fullname_style">{{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }}</a></div>
            <div class="post_user_username"><a href="{{ user_profile.username }}" class="post_user_nickname_style">@{{ post.author }}</a>

                 {% if post.author.verification %}
    <span class="verified_user_small"></span>
                {% endif %}

            </div>
            <div class="post_user_date"><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" class="post_user_date_style">{{ post.time_create }} {{ post.time_create|naturaltime }}</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_user_more">
        <div class="dropdown dropbtn" style="float:right;">
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                {% if request.user == post.author %}
                    <span><a href="{% url 'edit_post' post_slug=post.slug %}" class="post_user_edit">Edit</a></span>
                {% endif %}
                {% if user.is_authenticated and user == post.author %}
                    <span><a href="{% url 'delete_post' post_slug=post.slug %}" class="post_user_delete">Delete post</a></span>
                {% endif %}

                <span><a href="" class="post_user_complain">Report</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post_user_content">
        {{ post.content }}
    </div>
    <div class="post_user_action">



<div class="post_user_liked_post">


{% if liked_by_current_user %}
    <div class="unlike-button" id="unlike-button-{{ post.id }}" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}"></div>
{% else %}
    <div class="like-button" id="like-button-{{ post.id }}" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}"></div>
{% endif %}
    <div class="count_likevalue">
        <span class="like-count-value like_count_style" id="like-count-{{ post.id }}" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">{{ like_count }}</span>
    </div>


</div>

        <div class="containercomment_post">
            <!-- Unique identifier for each post -->
    <div class="post_user_comment_post" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">
        <span class="count_comment">{{ post.comments.count }}</span>
    </div>

        </div>
        <div class="post_user_share_post"></div>
        <div class="post_user_views_post">
            <div class="post_user_views_post_count"><span class="post_user_views_post_count_style">125025</span></div>
        </div>

    </div>



            <!-- Unique identifier for each comment form -->
    <div class="comment-form hidden" data-post-id="{{ post.id }}">
        <hr>
        <form action="{% url 'add_comment' post_id=post.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <textarea name="content" class="user_comment_style" placeholder="Write a comment..." required></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="img_sbmt"></button>
        </form>
    </div>

<!-- Display all comments -->
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <div class="comment-container">
        <div class="comment_post">
            {% if comment.author.avatar %}
                <img src="{{ comment.author.avatar.url }}" class="comment_author_img_style">
            {% else %}
                <img src="{% static 'twippie/img/avatar.png' %}" class="comment_author_img_style">
            {% endif %}
            <div class="comment_author"><a href="{% url 'user:profile_username' username=comment.author.username %}">{{ comment.author.first_name }}</a></div>
            <div class="comment_content" id="comment-content-{{ comment.id }}">{{ comment.content }}</div>
            <div class="comment_time">{{ comment.created_at }}
                <!--<span class="answer_comment_user"><a>Reply</a></span>-->
{% if comment.author == request.user %}
    <span id="edit-actions-{{ comment.id }}" class="edit_comment_user">
        <a href="#" onclick="editComment({{ comment.id }})" class="edit_comment_link">edit</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="saveComment(event, {{ comment.id }})" class="save_comment_link" style="display: none;">Save changes</a>
    </span>
    <span class="delete_comment_user"><a href="{% url 'delete_comment' comment_id=comment.id %}">delete</a></span>
{% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if not forloop.last %}
            <!-- If the current comment is not the last one, add a separator -->
            <hr class="solid_bottom">
        {% endif %}
        <span class="massage_save_comment_error"></span> <!-- Error message -->
        <span id="save-message-{{ comment.id }}" class="massage_save_comment"></span> <!-- Save message -->
    </div>
{% endfor %}
    <br>
</div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% else %}
    <p>No posts to display yet.</p>
{% endif %}




<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

{% endblock %}

views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from usercreatepost.forms import PostForm
from publication.models import Userpublication
from user.models import ProfileMyapp, Subscription
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.db.models import Q

@login_required
def create_post(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('home')

    # Get IDs of users subscribed by the current user
    subscribed_user_ids = Subscription.objects.filter(subscriber=request.user).values_list('target_user', flat=True)

    # Get all posts by authors subscribed by the current user
    subscribed_posts = Userpublication.objects.filter(author__in=subscribed_user_ids)

    # Get all posts by the current user
    own_posts = Userpublication.objects.filter(author=request.user)

    # Merge post lists
    all_posts = (subscribed_posts | own_posts).order_by('-time_create')

    # Get page object of posts to display
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 5)  # 5 posts per page

    try:
        page_posts = paginator.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page_posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page_posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'form': form, 'post_lists': page_posts, 'title': 'Myapp | News', 'page_number': page_number}
    return render(request, 'myapp/home.html', context)

def load_posts(request):
    # Get page number from the request
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)  # Set default value to 1

    # Get IDs of users subscribed by the current user
    subscribed_user_ids = Subscription.objects.filter(subscriber=request.user).values_list('target_user', flat=True)

    # Get all posts subscribed by the current user or authored by them
    all_posts = Userpublication.objects.filter(Q(author__in=subscribed_user_ids) | Q(author=request.user)).order_by('-time_create')

    # Create a Paginator object
    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 5)  # 5 posts per page

    try:
        # Get objects for the current page
        current_page_posts = paginator.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page number is not an integer, show the first page
        current_page_posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page number is out of range, return an empty response
        return JsonResponse({'posts': [], 'next_page_url': None})

    # Rendering HTML markup of posts
    html_posts = render_to_string('myapp/home_list.html', {'posts': current_page_posts})

    # Forming a list of posts to pass to JSON
    posts_list = [{'id': post.id, 'content': post.content} for post in current_page_posts]

    # Get URL for the next page if it exists
    next_page_url = None
    if current_page_posts.has_next():
        next_page_url = reverse('load_posts') + f'?page={current_page_posts.next_page_number()}'

    # Return JSON response with data about the posts, HTML markup, and URL of the next page
    return JsonResponse({'posts': posts_list, 'html_posts': html_posts, 'next_page_url': next_page_url})

